# if I have a 414 h in NY can I also contribute to a roth ira?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am a nurse in a hospital in the nys retirement system. $1900.00 was contributed by my employer to my 414h plan. I am under 50 years old- can I contribute to my roth ira and if so how much?